# How to add computer to domains with Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have successfully installed AD DS on one computer and added some users.

Now i want that my another computer with window XP should use the acounts which are in AD not the window XP build in Accounts.

i means when window XP starts with username and password then i can enter the username and password which i have defined for user in AD.

Is this possible

Comment: what version of XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on 'My Computer' and go to properties.
2. Go to the 'Computer Name' tab and click change
3. Change the 'Member Of' to Domain, and enter your domain name
4. You will be prompted for a user (AD Domain user) with rights that allow you to join.
5. Profit

Answer (score 1):

For Windows XP Pro:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295017

For Vista business:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295017

Windows 7 is pretty much the same.

You'll not be able to join any home version of Windows to an active directory domain. Furthermore, those local user accounts will still be available to log into. You'll have to change the local user accounts' passwords to prevent someone from logging into them. Also remember to migrate user data from a local account to the domain account if that's what you want to do. Use the free "[User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801(WS.10).aspx)" for that. Read all documentation. Your mileage my vary.

Comment: I have done that thanks and its working. But i had to change the dns server to the ip of the domain.        
One thing more now if user do some stuff will that be saved on local computer or my domain computer

Comment: Yes, all PCs in the domain need to have an Active Directory integrated DNS server to point to for much of the functionality of Active Directory to be available. All files will be saved on a local computer until you set up redirected folders in a domain policy.

Comment: Is it possible that the user desktop , my documents are saved on server folders. then what will happen if user format hi computer?

Comment: You can redirect a number of folders that belong to a user. It depends on which OS the clients are using (pre or post Vista). Check out the Wikipedia article on Folder Redirection and follow through on the related external links for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_redirection

Comment: BTW, change the DNS settings that clients get by editing the DHCP options that are handed out. If you're not using DHCP, then you really should be. Best of all would be to use Windows own DHCP service on an Active Directory member server.